# Traffic and airport simulator environment

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I want to build 2 separate RL models: one for controlling traffic lights on a raod and another for air traffic control incoming & outgoing planes in an airport.

### Road traffic simulator

I know of SUMO. Is there any other simulators?

### Airport air traffic control simulator

I couldn't find anything for this. Any recommendation would help.

Comment: First of all, Stack Overflow isn't a place to come to with a general description of a project and hope for recommendations - it's a place to come with a programming problem and ask for help solving it. Secondly, your question is not related to programming, but rather to general model building - which goes in stats.stackexchange.com, if anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [CityFlow](https://github.com/cityflow-project/CityFlow) is what you want. It is specifically designed for multi-agent RL:

"CityFlow is a multi-agent reinforcement learning environment for large-scale city traffic scenario." Check its features in their github page.

I am not aware of any airport traffic control simulator that can be used for RL.